# Big Oh in probability asymptotics

Tags: statistics, asymptotics, self-learning

This question is related to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3450979/big-oh-asymptotic-notation-for-real-sequences/3451010?noredirect=1#comment7093894_3451010).

Introduce the asymptotic [notation Big Oh in probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_in_probability_notation). Suppose that the real sequence $a_n\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.
If $C_1,C_2$ are constants, independent of $n$, then
$$\frac{C_1+O_p(a_n)}{C_2+O_p(a_n)}=\frac{C_1}{C_2}+O_p(a_n).$$
Why is it true?

**My proof based on Henry's comments**

Let $X_n,Y_n$ be $O_p(a_n)$ just for distinction of asymptotic terms in the numerator and in the denominator. Then
\begin{align}
\frac{C_1+X_n}{C_2+Y_n}&=\frac{C_1}{C_2+Y_n}+\frac{X_n}{C_2+Y_n}\\
&=\frac{C_1}{C_2}\frac{C_2}{C_2+Y_n}+\frac{X_n}{C_2+Y_n}\\
&=\frac{C_1}{C_2}\bigg(1-\frac{Y_n}{C_2+Y_n}\bigg)+\frac{X_n}{C_2+Y_n}.
\end{align}

We claim that $Y_n=O_p(a_n)=o_p(1)$ given that $a_n=o(1)$.

Let $\epsilon,\delta>0$. By hypothesis, $P(\lvert X_n\rvert\geq M_1\lvert a_n\rvert)\leq \epsilon$ for some $M_1>0$ and all sufficiently large $n$. Further, as $a_n\to0$ eventually $\delta\geq M\lvert a_n\rvert$, and then
$$P(\lvert Y_n\rvert\geq \delta\rvert)\leq P(\lvert X_n\rvert\geq M_1\lvert a_n\rvert)\leq \epsilon.$$ for all sufficiently large $n$.
This is exactly the definition of $Y_n$ being $o_p(1)$.

Then
\begin{align}
\frac{Y_n}{C_2+Y_n}&=Y_n\frac{\frac{1}{C_2}}{\frac{1}{C_2}}\frac{1}{C_2+Y_n}=
O_p(a_n)\frac{\frac{1}{C_2}}{1}\frac{1}{1+O_p(a_n)}\\
&=O_p(a_n)\frac{1}{C_2}\frac{1}{1+O_p(a_n)}=O_p(a_n)\frac{1}{C_2}\frac{1}{1+o_p(1)}\\
&=O_p(a_n)\frac{1}{C_2}O_p(1)=O_p(a_n)O_p(1)=O_p(a_n),
\end{align}
where the result $\frac{1}{1+o_p(1)}=O_p(1)$ is found in page 13 of [Van der Vaart's Asymptotic Statistics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521784506).

It follows that
$$\frac{C_1+O_p(a_n)}{C_2+O_p(a_n)}=\frac{C_1}{C_2}+O_p(a_n)+O_p(a_n)=\frac{C_1}{C_2}+O_p(a_n),$$
as desired.

Comment: Abusing the notation, you might consider this as $\dfrac{C_1+O_p(a_n)}{C_2+O_p(a_n)}$ $=\dfrac{C_1+\frac{C_1}{C_2}O_p(a_n)+O_p(a_n)}{C_2+O_p(a_n)}$ $= \dfrac{\frac{C_1}{C_2}\left(C_2 + O_p(a_n)\right) +O_p(a_n) }{C_2+O_p(a_n)}$ $= \dfrac{C_1}{C_2}+ \dfrac{O_p(a_n) }{C_2+O_p(a_n)} $ $= \dfrac{C_1}{C_2}+ O_p(a_n)$

Comment: @Henry You used $cO_p(a_n)=O_p(a_n)$ and $O_p(a_n)+O_p(a_n)=O_p(a_n)$, for any constant $c$. I didn't understand the last equality though. Why $O_p(a_n)/(C_2+O_p(a_n))=O_p(a_n)$?

Comment: Celine: You have $a_n \to 0$ so any positive constant $c$ is eventually (with arbitrarily high probability) much much bigger than anything which is $O_p(a_n)$

Comment: I meant that I didn't understand the equality $O_p(a_n)/(C_2+O_p(a_n))=O_p(a_n)$. Maybe I understand what you meant, but can you show this explicitly?

Comment: $C_2+O_p(a_n) = O_p(C_2)$ and $O_p(a_n) / O_p(C_2) = O_p(a_n)$.  You are in effect dividing something of the order of $a_n$ by something of the order of a positive constant so you still have something of the order of $a_n$

Comment: Great. I will write above my attempt which is inspired in your ideas.

Comment: @Henry Do you have any suggestion to show the last line, i.e., $O_p(a_n)/O_p(1)=O_p(a_n)$. Basically, I need to show that $1/O_p(1)=O_p(1)$. This is quite intuitive to me, but surprisingly, I could not show this. $1/O_p(1)=O_p(1)$ implies $O_p(a_n)O_p(1)=O_p(a_n)$

Comment: It may not work with $O_p(1)$ in general, but it does work here where you really have $\Theta_p(1)$ using an [extension of the notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations) meaning $\forall \varepsilon >0 \; \exists N_{\varepsilon}, \delta_{\varepsilon_1}, \delta_{\varepsilon_2} \; \text{ such that } P(\delta_{\varepsilon_1} \leq |a_n| \leq \delta_{\varepsilon_2}) \leq \varepsilon \; \forall n> N_{\varepsilon}$.  Then  $1/\Theta_p(1)=\Theta_p(1)$ by taking the reciprocals of the $\delta$s. Note  $\Theta_p(1)$ is $O_p(1)$ though not reverse

Comment: @Henry You are right. I'm still working on it. But I believe I can give a correct proof now. After, I rewrite my proof above.

Comment: @Henry I just updated my proof. This time, I didn't find anything wrong. Is that ok to you?